# Product stock notification in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-commerce

I have used drupal 7.38. My question is, I have used drupal commerce module. I have added 100 products in my site some products are in stock and some product are out of stocks. Show how can I know which product is out of stock.How can I create a views for out of product stocks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new View and select 'Commerce Product' as the type.
[image: Add View]

Configure other settings as required but the key thing to show products that are out of stock is to add a Filter Criteria for Stock amount.

Click 'Add' next to Filter Criteria and select the Stock field.
[image: Stock filter]

Then select 'Is greater than' and '0' as the criteria.
[image: criteria settings]

This will give you a list of products with no stock.
You'll need to add other fields and settings etc as required for your View.